# mobile.changePage Internal Linking

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Am Trying a single page template like this :-

```
 <div id="homePg" data-role="page">
 </div>  <!-- Home page -->

 <div  id="groupsPg" data-role="page">    
 </div>  <!-- Groups page -->
```

Data into the page contents are loaded dynamically from `ajax` call.

Am trying to navigate from my homepg to groups page onclick of any list generated.

```
     $.mobile.changePage('#groupsPg', {
                transition : "none"
            });
```

But due to some reasons this `changepage` event is not firing. I can get the `onclick` event fired but the change page event is not going through.

Comment: Maybe try `$(location).attr('href',"your_html.html");` where `your_html.html` is the HTML file containing your page `#groupsPg` (for this case, better separate the jquery mobile pages in different separate HTML files I think :S)?

Comment: @Littm : It works with different pages but I wanted to use one single html page due to some reasons.. Is it something with binding click events on the dynamic generated list?But click event fires not navigation.

Comment: oooh... :S Can you provide the definition of your `onclick` event? To which element do you apply the `onclick` event?

Comment: @Littm : Its is for anchor tags inside my ul>li>a `vclick` event.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this solution, let me know if this works:

```
$('#homePg').live('pagecreate',function(event){
    $("#your_anchor_id").bind("click", function(event) {
        $.mobile.changePage( "#groupsPg", { transition: "none"} );
    });  
});
```

Comment: Nope this isnt working either : though have used `on` instead of `live` for Jq 1.7+

Comment: argh! :( if I find anything I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I think that adding this code to your click event will do the trick:

```
window.location.href = ('url');
```

Try also this site:
http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-Window-Location-Href-URL.aspx

And this one:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Thanks but any reasons why doesnt `mobile.changePage` isnt working ?

Comment: Does my post helped you? It works?. If so, you can temporaily do as I said and handle anything else on pagechange. I will take a closer look at your problem soon.